# How/where to report abuse of Google services

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I've searched the Google Developer site and general help.  I can find information on reporting violations of my copyright.  I can't find information on reporting a site that explicitly fosters copyright violations using Google's services.  Specifically the site uses Google image search (I believe but am not certain using Google API) to return images based on user keyword search.  The images are presented hot-linked to their original source. So far - no problem.  There is also a link to the original source - no problem.  BUT the site offers the user the "service" of making modifications to the image - primarily upsizing and removing backgrounds - then the resulting modified image is stored on that site and the user invited to download the result.

They now filter out some sites - those most likely to want to enforce their copyrights - but continue to display copyright images, and creative commons images in ways that violate the license terms.  So I can't easily report infringement of my own work - undoubtedly I can find it but the core problem is the service, not just my work.

Google Ads are inserted throughout the search results.

It seems offering to modify images without the permission of the rights holder would violate Google terms of service?  But how do I report it?  I looked at many report forms - nothing seems to fit.

Comment: Perhaps you can see some traction here: https://support.google.com/code/contact/cloud_platform_report?hl=en. Keep in mind its for GCP.

Comment: Thank you.  That is the best possibility that I have seen so far.  I appreciate the assistance.  I know that this won't be a quick thing, I hope I can remember to report back.

Answer (score 1):

Laws vary by country. You need to contact a lawyer.

Did you register your copyright with the Copyright Office and did you receive a copyright? If yes, then you have a registration number.

Was the image attached to a tangible object such as a magazine advertisement, poster, book, box, dish plate, etc? If not, then you probably do not have a copyright that will stand in court.

It is not as simple as reporting an unfair use. You must demonstrate your legal standing on the issue and not your opinion and that usually requires going to court. If you provide your copyright registration, most vendors will review the issue. Send a certified letter to their registered business or legal address.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.  I'm sorry that I did not succeed in conveying the issue to you.  One of the other answers about where to report the issue described was more on point.

Comment: @Tanith - That link will accomplish nothing for your goal of copyright issues. That link is for reporting systems that violate Google's Terms of Service. That does not include your copyright issue.

Comment: I think deciding whether it does or does not violate Google's Terms of Service is really something only for Google.  My goal is to report a system, a site that explicitly fosters and invites copyright infringement.  My goal is not reporting a specific infringement of a specific work or works.